# TCPDF - Set check box Read Only

Tags: php, tcpdf

I  want to set the check-box as read-only in tcpdf.

I try this

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return false" />
```

But this is working for html only i mean in tcpdf its not working.

Answer (score 3):

try this for check-box as read-only in tcpdf ... it works for me

`<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" readonly="true" />`

Comment: I solved this problem.
I uesd checked="checked" . and thn its works.above solutions was not worked with tcpdf

Answer (score 0):

This is an example which should work in your case:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" checked="checked" readonly="true" /> <label for="agree">I agree </label><br /><br />
```